# Using jQuery to manipulate HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a javascript function that receives a string that is assumed to be HTML and removes all elements which would not be visible.  I'm not operating on the page here, just a string of HTML from anywhere.

At first it seemed using the :hidden selector would have been ideal, but I couldn't get that to work.  So I started playing with filter(), but haven't had success.

```
function StripInvisibleNodes(html) {
    var container = "" + html+ "";
    //var $onlyvisiblehtml = $(container).find(":hidden").remove(); // didn't work
    var $onlyvisiblehtml = $(container).find('*').filter(function() { return this.style.display == "none"; }).remove();
    var removed = $onlyvisiblehtml.html();
    return removed;
}
```

Update:  the following is the working solution

```
function StripInvisibleNodes(html) {
    $('body').append("<div id='tempspace' style='visibility:hidden'>" + content + "</div>");
    var $toremove = $('#tempspace').find("*").filter(':hidden'); 
    $toremove.remove();
    var resultstring = $('#tempspace').html();
    $('#tempspace').remove();
    return resultstring;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No HTML is considered `:visible` by jQuery if it's not been rendered in the DOM. For instance:

```
$test = $('<p>').filter(':visible');
```

will produce an empty jQuery object.

What you can do is render them briefly in the DOM, compute which elements are visible, and then remove them immediately. You can put them inside an element with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` if you don't want to risk it blinking into view:

```
$('#testspace').append('<p>');
$test2 = $('#testspace').children().filter(':visible');
console.log($test2);
$('#testspace').remove();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="testspace" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4NxBd/2/

Comment: Sounds like a good approach.  I tried to capture the idea in this modified function.

function StripInvisibleNodes(content) {
    $('body').append('<div id="testspace" style="visibility:hidden">' + content + '</div>');
    var $removed = $('#testspace').find("*").filter(':visible');
    var resultstring = $removed.html();
    $('#testspace').remove();
    return resultstring;
}

The result appears to still have display:none elements in it.  What did I miss?

Comment: Might be your HTML string. Your function appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/4NxBd/3/

Comment: I wish I could get the jsfiddle site to do something, anything at all.  It looks like a nifty tool.  I'll take you at your word that the function works there, but I wanted to test a more complex string, such as 

html = "<p>test 1</p><div><p style='display:none'>test 2</p><ul><li>one</li><li style='display:none'>two</li><li>three</li></ul></div>";

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NxBd/6/ -- we weren't using `.html()` correctly. However, there is an interesting problem: while `<p style="display:none"></p>` isn't visible, its parent `<div>` is. This is correct behavior. So while that fiddle logs only visible elements, you'll still see `display:none` a couple of times.

Comment: I made an interesting observation:  After doing 
var $removed = $('#testspace').find("*").filter(':visible');
I checked the value of $($removed.html()).find('*').length in my debugger, and it was the number of original elements, not just the visible ones.  Anyhow, thanks for your help, it ultimately led to my working solution, which I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

How about just selecting the visible elements?

```
$(":visible", container).html();
```